# clicking more than one button for physical simulator

Tags: python, python-3.x

For project 2 quiz game I am having trouble keeping track of 2 buttons being pressed. My code registers button 1 but does not allow me to check button 2,3,or 4.

```
while True:
    button1 = sensor.input('Button_1')
    button2 = sensor.input('Button_2')
    button3 = sensor.input('Button_3')
    button4 = sensor.input('Button_4')

    if button1 == 'pressed':
        print('button 1 is pressed')
        if button2 == 'pressed' or button3 == 'pressed':
```

this is the part of my code that reacts to button 1 but not the other ones.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What is `sensor`? Please provide a [mre] and add the tag for any library(s) you're using. You can [edit]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Would it work if you tried

```
elif button2 == 'pressed':
    print('button 2 is pressed')
```

and then so on and so forth for buttons 3 and 4?